# Move users / computers to a different organizational unit (OU) - impact?

Tags: active-directory, container

can I move an user/computer simply between OUs back and forth without any impact or is there something i have to consider? e.g. Services that no longer work then because their service accounts have been moved and stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just move a user or PC to a different OU because policies can be set to different OU's. A policy can control anything on a target pc. So if a user doesn't have certain rights, they suddenly may be granted with more rights. A policy can be affected to all users that log into a pc or for that specific user. So moving both users and computers can cause unwanted side-effects.

Comment: so beside the policies there is no other impact? like accounts or computers can not be found?

Comment: Well, technically speaking, one could check for a user's location through vbscripting too, so it is possible other sources also keep track of this data. It is not best practice though, but it is possible.